# Parse.com Store Array of booleans

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, boolean

I'm trying to store an array of booleans from a query but get null for the array.

Here is what I have:

```
PFQuery *businessInquiry = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"BusinessInquiry"];
businessInquiry.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyIgnoreCache;
[businessInquiry selectKeys:@[@"messageBody", @"emailAddress"]];
[businessInquiry orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[businessInquiry findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    self.businessInquiryEmailArray = [objects valueForKey:@"emailAddress"];
    self.businessInquiryMessageArray = [objects valueForKey:@"messageBody"];
    self.businessInquiryObjIdArray = [objects valueForKey:@"objectId"];
    self.businessisNewArray = [objects valueForKey:@"messageRead"]; //this column is a BOOL column in parse backend but it returns null
}];
```

My goal is to cross-reference this in the Detail Table View Controller in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and if it is new add an icon in the cell.imageView.image slot to indicate it's new visually like :

```
if ([self.isNew objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row] == FALSE) {
    //New message
} else {
    //Read
}
```

Why is it not storing the values?

I also tried :

```
self.businessiSNewArray = [[objects valueForKey:@"messageRead"] boolValue];
```

but that didn't work either. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I'm passing the arrays to the detail view controller like this:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
DetailTableViewController *detailVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailTableViewController"];
detailVC.emailAddressArray = self.businessInquiryEmailArray;
detailVC.messageBodyArray = self.businessInquiryMessageArray;
detailVC.objIds = self.businessInquiryObjID;
detailVC.isNew = self.businessisNewArray;
detailVC.title = @"Business Inquiries";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];
}
```

everything segues to its respective property in DetailVC header except the booleans. They return null

Comment: @LyndseyScott emailAddress, messageBody, objectId are string column types in backend. messageRead is bool column type

Comment: You aren't showing how you are storing the array, only how you are retrieving it - but you can't store an array of BOOL as BOOL is not an object. You would have to box/unbox the BOOL with an NSNumber

Comment: Yes that's the problem @Paulw11 storing the objects in the businessisNewArray. I'm just passing them to the detailViewController like this : detailVC.isNew = self.businessisNewArray . isNew is another NSArray  property in the Detail View Controller. I will try to research and see if there is anything online about storing them as NSNumbers. thanks

Comment: Wait... Your other arrays are storing properly?

Comment: Yes @LyndseyScott , the only issue is storing boolean values into an array everything else is fantastic.

Comment: @LyndseyScott i even tried your suggestion for PFObject in objects but it returns null as well, i think Paul has a point, it has to be turned into a number but I dont know how to do that. Should I just not use the boolean column in the backend and just use a string representation of 1 or 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is kind of related to what Paul was saying, but its kind of not. Yes you can box them as a number but its irrelevant in your circumstance.

The issue is one of those things that if you knew what it was, you would slap your self in the forehead and say, ohhh duhhh!

Simply put, you've restricted your query to not include the messageRead column type, disregarding what type of column it is, it could be anything (string, number etc), but the fact you have restricted it by *excluding* it in 'selectKeys:` is why it's returning null:

> selectKeys: Make the query restrict the fields of the returned PFObjects to include only the provided keys.

**Reference :** https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/selectKeys:

just a simple overlook. If those are the only 3 columns in your class in the backend, there really is no need to use `selectKeys:` since it will return all the objects regardless, and your just passing them into a recyclable array.

Comment: it works!! your a blessing thxs slaps myself in the forehead and says "OH DUH!"